# For a RESTful service - How does a client find valid values for a resource attribute?

Tags: rest, jsonschema, discovery, capability

As a part of capabilities discovery for a resource provided by a RESTful API, I am looking for a way for the service to announce accepted values for an attribute. Consider the following example, where an `apple` resource has an attribute `color`:

```
GET /apples/17
```

This request yields:

```
{
  "name": "My yummy apple",
  "color": "green"
}
```

For a client to understand what `color`values are valid when for instance `PUT`ting a new version of this apple, I can think of many possible ways. However I haven't found any best practices here. The HTTP OPTIONS verb seems not to be made for this fine-grained kind of discovery. Should I just add an array attribute to the `/apples` collection:

```
GET /apples
```

Response:

```
{
  ...
  "colorValues": ["red", "green"]
}
```

Are there any better and more commonly used ways?

**EDIT:**
Just realized that one possible way would be to add a resources for schemas for all "real" resources. Something liked `GET /schemas/apple` that would yield a JSON Schema representation for the `apple` resource. Modified example from json-schema.org:

```
{
    "id": "http://foo.bar/schema#",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "schema for an apple resource",
    "type": "object",
    ...
    "colorValues": {
        "enum": [ "red", "green" ]
    }
}
```

I have not found any examples of this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Hyper-Schema is great for this kind of thing.

```
GET /apples/17
```

- 

```
HTTP/1.1 OK
Content-Type: application/json; profile="/schema/apple"

{
  "id": 17,
  "name": "My yummy apple",
  "color": "green"
}
```

A client can then dereference the hyper-schema at `schema/apple` to learn what links are available to follow next.

```
GET /schema/apple
```

- 

```
HTTP/1.1 OK
Content-Type: application/schema+json

{
  "id": "http://foo.bar/schema/apple",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": { "type": "string", "readOnly": true },
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "color": { "enum": ["red", "green"] }
  },
  "required": ["id", "name", "color"],
  "links": [
    { "rel": "self", "href": "/apple/{id}" },
    {
      "rel": "http://foo.bar/relation/edit",
      "href": "/apple/{id}",
      "method": "PUT",
      "schema": { "$ref": "#" }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is a JSON Schema like you are familiar with, but contains an extra keyword `links` that describes links you can follow from this resource.  The client evaluates the `href` URI Templates using the values from the original JSON data.  So, in this case, the link evaluates to ...

```
{
  "rel": "http://foo.bar/relation/edit",
  "href": "/apple/17",
  "method": "PUT",
  "schema": { "$ref": "#" }
}
```

This link directs the client that it can make a `PUT` request to `/apple/17` and the request body should validate against the schema at `/schema/apple` (`{ "$ref": "#" }` means this schema).

This gives you both a human readable and a machine executable description of your functionality.  The machine executable part is a big deal because changes can often be made to your API without breaking existing clients.

NOTE: This code is written in JSON Hyper-Schema draft-04.  There is a new version draft-05 that came out recently.  It makes a few controversial changes.  I'm still recommending draft-04 at this point.  The specification can be found at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-luff-json-hyper-schema-00.

Comment: I think this approach captures my ambitions to keep the definitions and schema quite compact. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways is having two resources: `apples` and `colours`. It will be very easy for your potential clients to get available colours in a restful way. What about hypermedia? There are **[many standards](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/)**, you can create your own but it's better to stick with some widely-used.

For example, if you want to implement it following [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html), getting apple will look like:

```
GET /apples/17

{
  "name": "My yummy apple",
  "_links": {
     "self": {
       "href": "/apples/17"
     },
   },
   "colour": {
     "id": "green",
     "href": "/colours/green"
   }
}
```

And what about listing all colours? Sth like this:

```
GET /colours

{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "/colours"
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "colours": [
      {
         "_links": {
           "self": {
             "href": "/colours/green"
           }
         },
         "id": "green"
      },
      {
         "_links": {
           "self": {
             "href": "/colours/red"
           }
         },
         "id": "red"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It's the modern way to design API adopted for example by [Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream/latest/developerguide/appstream-api-rest.html)

> The Amazon AppStream web service is a resource-based API that uses
>   Hypertext Application Language (HAL). HAL provides a standard way for
>   expressing the resources and relationships of an API as hyperlinks.
>   Using HAL, you use HTTP methods (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE) to submit
>   requests and receive information about the API in the response.
>   Applications can use the information returned to explore the
>   functionality of the API.

**Edit:**

If different colours are allowed for different entities, you can do sth like

```
GET /apples/17

{
  "name": "My yummy apple",
  "_links": {
     "self": {
       "href": "/apples/17"
     },
     "available_colours": {
       "href": "/apples/17/available_colours"
     }
   },
   "colour": {
     "id": "green",
     "href": "/colours/green"
   },      
   "_embedded": {
     "available_colours": [
       {
         "_links": {
           "self": {
             "href": "/colours/green"
           }
         },
         "id": "green"
       },
       {
         "_links": {
           "self": {
             "href": "/colours/red"
           }
         },
         "id": "red"
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you see it's very flexible structure.

Comment: Valuable input - and I can definitely see the use! But in a more general sense (eg to convey maximum allowed value for a set of integer value attributes) it appears to me as quite tedious? Say for instance that there is a total of 5 different apple colors, but different colors are allowed for different entities?

Comment: @MarcusJohansson Hello, I have edited the answer and added some extra example with `available_colours` for specified entity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate your input on this.